# Flex/AS/PHP Как принять XML из PHP-сервиса в Flex

Tags: php, actionscript-3, apache-flex

Есть PHP сервис в котором есть функция `getMarkings()`. Она возвращает сформированую XML переменную `return $doc` . Формируется он правильно. С этим проблем нет. Проблема в том как принять его во флекс проекте под AIR.

Я делал следущее:

1. Создал проект flex с Air
2. В проекте открыл окно Data/Service -> connect to Data/Service -> PHP -> Выбрал PHP файл с функцией -> сервис добавился успешно, в окне видна функция `getMarkings()`.
3. Нажимаю правой кнопкой мишы на `getMarkings()` и выбираю"Test Operation"
4. И получаю окно с такой ошибкой:

> InvocationTargetException:There was an error while invoking the
>   operation. Check your operation inputs or server code and try invoking
>   the operation again.